# What is M stands for in MI2S interface

Tags: audio, protocols

I want to know full form of MI2S. Through wikipedia page i find about 
[I2S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S).

I²S (Inter-IC Sound), pronounced I-squared-S, is an electrical serial bus interface standard used for connecting digital audio devices together.

So what is M stands for in MI2S.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple. The protocol is the same as I2S, just more channels are supported.

Page 76
[Example](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/sd410/snapdragon-410-processor-device-specification.pdf)